# Gradle is searching on Artifactory for a jar library file but it is an aar file

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory, artifact

I'm new to Artifactory and Gradle, and I'm experiencing the following problem:

I have published on Artifactory an .aar file, which is the following file:
Lib-debug-1.0.0.aar

Now I want to resolve this dependency from a Gradle project, and I've written this code:

In settings.gradle, I've written this code:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        //name 'Lib-debug-1.0.0.aar'
        url 'https://wbste.com/art/IN-DH-commands'
        credentials {
            username = "user"
            password = "pwd"
        }
    }
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
}
}
```

In app/build.gradle file, I've written this code:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        //name 'Lib-debug-1.0.0.aar'
        url 'https://wbste.com/art/IN-DH-commands'
        credentials {
            username = "user"
            password = "pwd"
        }
    }
}
}

implementation("com.wfm.egrids:Lib-debug:1.0.0:aar")
```

When I build the project, the following errors are returned:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

 1 Task failed with an exception.
 -----------
 What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDevAretiDebugKotlin'.
 > Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task 
 ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDevAretiDebugKotlin'
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devAretiDebugCompileClasspath'.
       > Failed to transform Lib-debug-1.0.0-aar.jar (com.wfm.egrids:Lib-debug:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
     > Could not find Lib-debug-1.0.0-aar.jar (com.wfm.egrids:Lib-debug:1.0.0).
       Searched in the following locations:
           https://wbste.com/art/IN-DH-commands/com/wfm/egrids/Lib-debug/1.0.0/Lib-debug-1.0.0-aar.jar
```

It seems like I'm searching for a .jar file, but my file isn't this:

https://wbste.com/art/IN-DH-commands/com/wfm/egrids/Lib-debug/1.0.0/Lib-debug-1.0.0-aar.jar

But this:

https://wbste.com/art/IN-DH-commands/com/wfm/egrids/Lib-debug/1.0.0/Lib-debug-1.0.0.aar

Where could I have set I want to search for a .jar file? How could I write I want to search for an .aar file?

If I write:

```
 implementation(group: 'com.wfm.egrids', name: 'Lib-debug', version: '1.0.0', ext: 'aar')
```

I get the following error:

```
 "Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact"
```

Any help will be truly appreciated! I'm stuck on this problem since two weeks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to replace this line:

```
implementation("com.wfm.egrids:Lib-debug:1.0.0@aar")
```